# Angular animation value removed on route change

Tags: angular, angular-animations

I'm using Angular animation to animate transition between my (mobile) apps pages. On one of the pages I have a toggle animation that allows the user to toggle a

element:

```js
export const toggleBioContent = trigger('toggleBioContent', [
  state('collapsed', style({ height: '180px' })),
  state('expanded', style({ height: '*' })),
  transition('expanded <=> collapsed', [
    animate('225ms ease-in-out'),
  ]),
])
```

component:

```html
<div class="overview">
  <p (click)="showBiography = !showBiography" [@toggleBioContent]="showBiography ? 'expanded' : 'collapsed'">
    <img src="https://www.themoviedb.org/t/p/w120_and_h133_face/8nytsqL59SFJTVYVrN72k6qkGgJ.jpg" alt="some guy" />
    {{ biography }}
  </p>
</div>
```

This works fine, the user can toggle the p element. The issue is that if the element is collapsed and the user navigates to another page the p element loses the `180px` and the whole p element is visible.

As you can see in the gif, I toggle the p element a few times, collapse it and then navigate to another page and then the whole p element is shown. I can see in the dev tools that the `height: 180px` value is removed.

[image]